# SQL Join outputting Empty field

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, join, select

I need to produce a Query that pulls columns from two tables and outputs the id of each job, who worked on it and hour many hours were spent. t1.c1 = Employee's name, t2.c1 = JobId, t2.c2 = HoursWorked.

```
SELECT t2.c1, t1.c1, t2.c2
FROM t1
RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.c1 = t2.c1;
```

This outputs t2.c1 & t2.c2 correctly but leaves t1.c1 blank

Comment: try with simple JOIN

Comment: simple JOIN throws a syntax error in FROM clause

Comment: can you post a sample data

Answer (score 0):

If you need  t1.c1  not  null values  you should use left join

```
SELECT t2.c1, t1.c1, t2.c2
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.c1 = t2.c1;
```

or if you are looking for only exact match you should use inner join

```
SELECT t2.c1, t1.c1, t2.c2
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.c1 = t2.c1;
```

Comment: Left join leaves t2.c1 & t2.c2 blank while filling t1.c1, Inner join leaves all columns blank.

Comment: then update your question   add a proper data sample  .. and the expected  result  please

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this without using any join

```
select T2.JobId,T1.Employeename,T2.HoursWorked from T1,T2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not much clear but i guess you need something below(as you said "This outputs t2.c1 & t2.c2 correctly but leaves t1.c1 blank")

```
SELECT t2.c1, t1.c1, t2.c2
FROM t1
RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.c1 = t2.c1
union
SELECT t2.c1, t1.c1, t2.c2
FROM t1
left JOIN t2 ON t1.c1 = t2.c1
```